# nginx proxy_pass not work with hosts file

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose config (it`s part with my nginx service)

```
  nginx-service:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-service
    command: /bin/bash -c "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
    restart: always
    networks:
      system-network:
        aliases:
          - nginx-service.docker
    extra_hosts:
      - serverIp:${CURRENT_SERVER_IP}
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8081:8081
```

In this server has a docker container that is out docker-compose network and is created automatically if necessary.

I want the current ip of the server to be in the .env file and for this i use extra_hosts and this nginx config for proxy:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name first.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://serverIp:8082/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And this really work! Because this container always up and has port 8082.

But this config does not work, and I can not fix it. Can you tell me how I can fix this.

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name second.example.com;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;

    location / {
        set $status_proxy 0;

        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_connect_timeout       960s;
        proxy_send_timeout          960s;
        proxy_read_timeout          960s;
        send_timeout                960s;

        if ($cookie_testingPort ~* "(60[\d]{3})") {
            proxy_pass http://serverIp:$cookie_testingPort;
            set $status_proxy 1;
        }

        if ($status_proxy = 0) {
            return 400;
        }
    }
}
```

When i am redirected from second.example.com - nginx return me "502 Bad Gateway" though i see in cookie testingPort with correctly port for docker container and container really has in server with CURRENT_SERVER_IP which is specified in the hosts file inside container with NGINX

Comment: What is the meaning of `if ($cookie_testingPort ~* "(60[\d]{3})")` or what do you want to achieve with it? Do you use a port to connect to `second.example.com`?

Comment: second.example.com - This URL should redirect the user to a container that is created on a specific range of ports from 6000 and then following regExp in this condition. To connect to it, I wanted to use the port from the cookie and the address, which is redefined in the hosts file.  

If I specify the address correctly, without redefining it in the host, then this condition and redirect work correctly. But I would like to understand how to make it work with the redefined URL in the hosts file

Comment: If I understand correctly, your variable `$cookie_testingPort` is undefined. Do you have extra code where you defined that variable? Also you regex checks for "60" + 3 digits, so "6000" will not match.

Comment: Sorry 60000 port i mean, $cookie_testingPort  - at the time of raising, the nginx is really undefined, but it is read from the user from the cookie when it is redirected to this URL and then after checking the validation it should be sent to the container but at that moment it can no longer read the information recorded in the file hosts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why it does not work

You are setting `proxy_pass http://serverIp:$cookie_testingPort`, which means it has a dynamic/variable value. When nginx has a dynamic/variable value for `proxy_pass` it will try to resolve that domain name in runtime (upon the incoming request) with the help of a dns server and it will ignore `/etc/hosts`. In order for "runtime resolve" to work you need to set `resolver {{ip}}` in nginx config and that ip should have a dns server installed, but:

- you can not use `resolver 127.0.0.1` because you don't have dns server installed in that image
- you can not use `resolver 127.0.0.11` (network dns of current docker-compose) because it does not know anything about `serverIp`

#### Solution 1:

> In this server has a docker container that is out docker-compose network and is created automatically if necessary.

Since that "outside container" is a docker container it belongs to some network. If you manage to connect your `nginx-service` container to the network of that "outside container" - you should be able to set `resolver 127.0.0.11` and call the "outside container" by its service name. You can refer to networks outside of docker-compose as "external". Here is [one random example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522543/how-to-access-container-from-another-compose-that-connected-to-external-network) on how to do it and the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1).

#### Solution 2:

You can use a template to generate `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/second.example.com.conf`

```
# filename: ./second.example.com.template

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name second.example.com;

    location / {
        set $status_proxy 0;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        if ($cookie_testingPort ~* "(60[\d]{3})") {
            proxy_pass http://${CURRENT_SERVER_IP}:$cookie_testingPort;
            set $status_proxy 1;
        }

        if ($status_proxy = 0) {
            return 400;
        }
    }
}
```

```
# part of docker-compose.yml

  nginx-service:
    ...
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./second.example.com.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/second.example.com.template
    environment:
      - "CURRENT_SERVER_IP=${CURRENT_SERVER_IP}"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst '$$CURRENT_SERVER_IP' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/second.example.com.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/second.example.com.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

What happens there is:

- mount `/etc/nginx/conf.d/second.example.com.template`
- set env var `CURRENT_SERVER_IP` inside the container
- upon initialization `envsubst`:

  - reads `/etc/nginx/conf.d/second.example.com.template`
  - substitutes $CURRENT_SERVER_IP with the needed ip
  - saves the result as `/etc/nginx/conf.d/second.example.com.conf`
- nginx starts